# Subjonctif présent du verbe « choir »

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif, verbes-défectifs

J’ai constaté que le verbe choir n’a pas de [subjonctif](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/choir/). Pourtant, en voulant décliner la célèbre formule « à elle de tirer la chevillette pour que la bobinette `<choir>` » un tel subjonctif m’est bien utile.
J’ai même pensé à faire dans le néologisme de déclinaison « choisse » mais… c’est délicat. Comment donc, tout en restant correct, peut-on utiliser le verbe choir dans un cas où le subjonctif s’impose ? (Il s’impose d’autant plus ici que pour des raisons littéraires j’ai besoin de calquer une formule consacrée.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il est vrai que la plupart des verbes dits "défectifs" ont des conjugaisons qui peuvent être assez facilement complétées, Dans le cas de *choir* les verbes *déchoir* et *échoir* indiquent que la conjugaison de ce verbe au subjonctif est probablement la même que la conjugaison en -o- d'*asseoir* (d'où la probable raison de la perte de ce temps et de l'imparfait, car il est à ces temps homophone de *choyer*):

- que je choie
- que tu choies
- qu'il choie
- que nous choyions
- que vous choyiez
- qu'ils choient

Comment: Pas mal. C’était l’intuition que j’avais avant que le doute qui me tenaillât n’ait fini de me faire consulter mon ouvrage de référence.

Comment: Et l'imparfait du subjonctif donnerait *que je chusse*, j'imagine...

Comment: C'est ce que je présumerais.

Answer (score 0):

... pour que la bobinette puisse choir. Pas besoin de calquer une forme pour le Subjonctif present 3-e personne,surtout si la "langue" a voulu l'ignorer.

Comment: Certes mais autrement, nous n’aurions pas jouis de cet excellent prétexte à la masturbation intellectuelle :)